# How to pass environment variables in parameters in Azure pipelines yaml?

Tags: azure-devops, parameters, environment-variables, azure-pipelines

In Azure I compute a subscription to deploy resources in the new subscription,
I need to pass its subscription ID in the next template to deploy resources on it.

So after obtaining the subscription ID in stage2, we put this as environment variable in powershell script, then we would like to send this to the stage3 (both stages are using differents pool), stage3 is in the separated template spoke1.yaml as parameter.

Actually in stage2 at the end I can print its value, but I can't pass this value as parameter, how do we do that?

This is the code, in the template I could not obtain the value.

```
 - stage: 'Stage2'
    dependsOn: STAGE1
    jobs:
      - job: Deploy
        displayName: Prepare subscription
        steps:
            - template: '../tasks/create_service_connection.yaml'
              parameters:
                  CIName: ${{ parameters.CIName }}
                  projectName: ${{ parameters.projectName }}
            - powershell: Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=subscriptionidoutput;isOutput=true]$(subscriptionId)"
            - powershell: Write-Host "This subscription ID I want to pass " $(subscriptionId) (This actually works)
  - template: spoke1.yaml
    parameters:
          ServiceConnectionName: "Myserviceconnection"
          CIName: ${{ parameters.CIName }}
          projectName: ${{ parameters.projectName }}
          subscriptionId: What do I need to put here?
```

This is the part of the template where I try to use this parameter

```
 - template: '../tasks/create_storage_account_for_tfstate.yaml'
   parameters:
     subscriptionId: ${{ parameters.subscriptionId }}
```

The template begins from the stage level, then jobs and tasks, it uses another pool.

The parameter is declared on the top of the template, only in subscriptionID I'm getting the problem, the other parameters work fine, the value is empty.

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1307

Answer (score 0):

The way I am doing it, is to access the variable directly in the template.

In you case you could access it like:

```
$(subscriptionidoutput)
```

It should work.